# Apache 2.4 require password on subdomain not seems to be working

Tags: apache, apache2.4

My final foal is to as password on every sub domain but not www and local.

> I followed the https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/auth.html guide. "Visitors coming from that address will not be able to see the content covered by this directive. If, instead, you have a machine name, rather than an IP address, you can use that."

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
<If "req('Host') == 'dev.domain.ee'">
    AuthUserFile /path/dev/.htpasswd
</If>
<If "req('Host') == 'test.domain.ee'">
    AuthUserFile /path/test/.htpasswd
</If>
<If "req('Host') == 'prelive.domain.ee'">
    AuthUserFile /path/prelive/.htpasswd
</If>
<RequireAll>
    Require all granted
    Require not host dev.domain.ee test.domain.ee  prelive.domain.ee
</RequireAll>
```

Still it does not work by not asking password on dev.domain.ee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my own problem.

```
<RequireAny>
     Require host www.domain.ee
     Require local
     Require valid-user
</RequireAny>
```

That telles to require valid user for all other cases except localhost and www.domain.ee